# How to create a steady state flow of fantasy races using matrices and eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to create a way to 'populate' a fantasy location with different fantasy races, but I want to avoid cultural/ethnic monoliths.

I remember being taught about steady-state population flows at university in our introduction to matrices, so I dug around and found this [familiar example](https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/using-eigenvectors-to-find-steady-state-population-flows-cd938f124764)

> Imagine Seattle and Portland both have populations of 500,000. Each year, 5 percent of Seattle’s population moves to Portland and 20 percent of Portland’s population moves to Seattle. The rest don’t move. This pattern repeats every year, forever.

My thought would be that rather than model the population of two places, it would be possible to model the population of one place, but with each number being the amount of humans, dwarves, elves etc in the same place. So in that case the above problem statement would be:

> Imagine Waterdeep has a population of both humans and elves of 500. Each year, 5 percent of elves 'become' human (they leave waterdeep and are replaced) and 20 percent of humans become elves (they leave waterdeep and are replaced). The rest don’t move. This pattern repeats every year, forever.

However, I can see that not working because eventually you just get an all human location which I'm trying to avoid.

In this case I'd have to say that the percentage change isn't fixed, it's somehow related to the current population numbers of all species.

Now it's sounding like [matrix population models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_population_models) which is even *further* out of my comfort zone. Even more so that I'm not interested in looking at birth rates but immigration/emigration which it looks like that skips.

So what I'd like to know, is there way of generating a 'migration' matrix, like in the medium post,

$$A =     \begin{bmatrix}
    0.95 & 0.2  \\
    0.05 & 0.8 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

that a) takes into account the current populations of all races (i.e. to account for rules like too many elves put off dwarves, gnomes like to live in the same place as dwarves) and b) would never give you a population of zero, for all but one of the races?

Comment: The more accurate analogy to your original example is to have $X$ percent humans "become" dwarves and $Y$ percent dwarves "become" human, yearly.

Comment: @user619894 that's a great analogy I had completely missed